# Can AppEngine python threads last longer than the original request?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

We're trying to use the new python 2.7 threading ability in Google App Engine and it seems like the created thread is getting killed before it finishes running.  Our scenario:

- User sends a message to the server
- We update the user's data
- We spawn a thread to do some more heavy duty processing
- We return a response to the user before waiting for the heavy duty processing to finish

My assumption was that the thread would continue to run after the request had returned, as long as it did not exceed the total request time limit.  What we're seeing though is that the thread is randomly killed partway through it's execution.  No exceptions, no errors, nothing.  It just stops running.

Are threads allowed to exist after the response has been returned?  This does not repro on the dev server, only on live servers.

We could of course use a task queue instead, but that's a real pain since we'd have to set up a url for the action and serialize/deserialize the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'Sandboxing' section of this page:
 http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python27/using27.html#Sandboxing
indicates that threads cannot run past the end of the request.

Answer (score 3):

[Deferred tasks](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred.html) are the way to do this. You don't need a URL or serialization to use them:

```
from google.appengine.ext import deferred
deferred.defer(myfunction, arg1, arg2)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. I wish some of these things were more visible in the documentation.